# Flutter Container height same as parent height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to overlay a Card with a white container, but the container always needs a height (otherwise it's not displayed). I want it to be as big as its parent, the stack. How can I make this work? The height of the card varies. I guess I'm missing something ;)

```
return new Stack(
 children: <Widget>[
  new Card( ... ),
  new Container(color: Colors.white70),
 ]
);
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use a `Positioned.fill` to force a stack child to fill `Stack`.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Card(),
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Container(color: Colors.red),
    )
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 14):

```
height: double.infinity
```

It worked for me in case of container

Comment: easier than wrapping the widget