# Fit Container Widget Height to Parent Row Height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a web application with the following layout:

[image]

I am trying to create a flutter application with a similar layout and this is what I have so far:

[image]

For reproduction purposes, my layout logic is the following (all my code is in the `main.dart` file for this example):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Assemblers Tasks',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Assembly Tasks'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String dropdownValue;

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> buildItems = [];
  getBuilds() {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [];
    items.add({"id": 10, "vehicleModel": "A10", "vehicleNumber": "TEST-00010"});
    setState(() {
      buildItems = items;
    });
  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> buildSections = [];
  getSections() {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [];
    items.add({
      "id": 5,
      "section": "Front",
    });
    items.add({
      "id": 15,
      "section": "Rear",
    });
    setState(() {
      buildSections = items;
    });
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getSystems(String buildSectionId) async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [];
    if (int.parse(buildSectionId) == 5) {
      items.add({
        "id": 4,
        "system": "Hydraulics",
      });
      items.add({
        "id": 20,
        "system": "High Voltage",
      });
    }
    return items;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getBuilds();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 275.0,
                  child: DropdownButton(
                      value: dropdownValue,
                      hint: Text("Choose Build"),
                      isExpanded: true,
                      items: buildItems
                          .map<Map<String, String>>((Map<String, dynamic> item) {
                            String id = item["id"].toString();
                            String name = item["vehicleModel"] + " " + item["vehicleNumber"];
                            return {"id": id, "name": name};
                          })
                          .toList()
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((Map<String, String> item) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: item["id"],
                              child: Text(item["name"]),
                            );
                          })
                          .toList(),
                      onChanged: (String newValue) {
                        getSections();
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownValue = newValue;
                        });
                      }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 150.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "SECTION",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 17.3,
                        letterSpacing: 1.35,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 150.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                  color: Color(0xff444444),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "SYSTEM",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 17.3,
                        letterSpacing: 1.35,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60.0,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 36.0),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 72.0),
                    color: Color(0xff666666),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        "TASK",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 17.3,
                          letterSpacing: 1.35,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12, width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 225,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: buildSections.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        String section = buildSections[index]["section"] != null ? buildSections[index]["section"] : "";
                        String buildSectionId = buildSections[index]["id"].toString();
                        return Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: 150.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                  right: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black12,
                                    width: 1.0,
                                  ),
                                  bottom: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black12,
                                    width: 1.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 16.0),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: RotatedBox(
                                        quarterTurns: -1,
                                        child: Text(
                                          section.toUpperCase(),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15.0,
                                            letterSpacing: 1.2,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                  ),
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                                      child: Icon(Icons.image),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            FutureBuilder(
                              future: getSystems(buildSectionId),
                              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot systemsSnap) {
                                if (systemsSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                  return Container(
                                    height: 100.0,
                                    width: 200.0,
                                    child: Text("Please wait..."),
                                  );
                                } else if (systemsSnap.hasError) {
                                  return Container(
                                    height: 100.0,
                                    width: 200.0,
                                    child: Text("Oops! There was an error!"),
                                  );
                                }
                                return Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 256.0,
                                      child: ListView.builder(
                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                        itemCount: systemsSnap.data.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                          Map<String, dynamic> system = systemsSnap.data[index];
                                          String systemName = system["system"];
                                          return Row(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Container(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 16.0),
                                                width: 150.0,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  border: Border(
                                                    right: BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.black12,
                                                      width: 1.0,
                                                    ),
                                                    bottom: BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.black12,
                                                      width: 1.0,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                child: Column(
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Align(
                                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                      child: RotatedBox(
                                                        quarterTurns: -1,
                                                        child: Text(
                                                          systemName.toUpperCase(),
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 15.0,
                                                            letterSpacing: 1.2,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    Padding(
                                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                                    ),
                                                    Align(
                                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                      child: FloatingActionButton(
                                                        child: Icon(Icons.image),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO action
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.library_books),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO action
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.list),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO action
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.history),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO action
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The above code is ready to be pasted into the main.dart file and preview on a the virtual device (preferably tablet).

So far I have tried the solutions I found on these posts to no avail: 
 - [Make container widget fill parent vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155208/make-container-widget-fill-parent-vertically) 
 - [Flutter Container height same as parent height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078707/flutter-container-height-same-as-parent-height) 
 - [Flutter expand Container to fill remaining space of Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54839870/flutter-expand-container-to-fill-remaining-space-of-row) 
 - [The equivalent of wrap_content and match_parent in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257668/the-equivalent-of-wrap-content-and-match-parent-in-flutter)

Since the **Row** that contains the section **Container** also has a **ListView** being generated with the **FutureBuilder**, the height of the **Row** automatically expands to fit the **ListView**. I also want the section **Container** to expand to the same height as the how the **Row** widget is expanding; i.e., The bottom border of the section **Container** that says *FRONT*, should be aligned with the bottom border of the **Hight Voltage** system and the right border of the *FRONT* section **Container**, should go all the way to the top.

I already spent 3 days without a resolution.

---

### Edit

I have tried the suggestion on the answer provided by @MaadhavSharma but I get the following exception:

> ════════ Exception Caught By rendering library ════════════════════════════
>   The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
>   BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.

Comment: Why don't you use [Table](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html)?

Comment: @RémiRousselet I haven't used tables before. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I tried with the table but it doesn't fit my purpose. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I changed a little the structure to make it work, here is the entire `build()` method:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 275.0,
                  child: DropdownButton(
                      value: dropdownValue,
                      hint: Text("Choose Build"),
                      isExpanded: true,
                      items: buildItems
                          .map<Map<String, String>>((Map<String, dynamic> item) {
                        String id = item["id"].toString();
                        String name = item["vehicleModel"] + " " + item["vehicleNumber"];
                        return {"id": id, "name": name};
                      })
                          .toList()
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((Map<String, String> item) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: item["id"],
                          child: Text(item["name"]),
                        );
                      })
                          .toList(),
                      onChanged: (String newValue) {
                        getSections();
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownValue = newValue;
                        });
                      }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 150.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "SECTION",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 17.3,
                        letterSpacing: 1.35,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 150.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                  color: Color(0xff444444),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "SYSTEM",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 17.3,
                        letterSpacing: 1.35,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60.0,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 36.0),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 72.0),
                    color: Color(0xff666666),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        "TASK",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 17.3,
                          letterSpacing: 1.35,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12, width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 225,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: buildSections.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        String section = buildSections[index]["section"] != null ? buildSections[index]["section"] : "";
                        String buildSectionId = buildSections[index]["id"].toString();
                        return IntrinsicHeight(
                          child:  Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                width: 150.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  border: Border(
                                    right: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.black12,
                                      width: 1.0,
                                    ),
                                    bottom: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.black12,
                                      width: 1.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 16.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: RotatedBox(
                                          quarterTurns: -1,
                                          child: Text(
                                            section.toUpperCase(),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 15.0,
                                              letterSpacing: 1.2,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                    ),
                                    Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: FloatingActionButton(
                                        child: Icon(Icons.image),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              FutureBuilder(
                                future: getSystems(buildSectionId),
                                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot systemsSnap) {
                                  if (systemsSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                    return Container(
                                      height: 100.0,
                                      width: 200.0,
                                      child: Text("Please wait..."),
                                    );
                                  } else if (systemsSnap.hasError) {
                                    return Container(
                                      height: 100.0,
                                      width: 200.0,
                                      child: Text("Oops! There was an error!"),
                                    );
                                  }

                                  return

                                    Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 256.0,
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: systemsSnap.data.map<Widget>((e) => Container(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 16.0),
                                          width: 150.0,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            border: Border(
                                              right: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.black12,
                                                width: 1.0,
                                              ),
                                              bottom: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.black12,
                                                width: 1.0,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Align(
                                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                child: RotatedBox(
                                                  quarterTurns: -1,
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    e["system"].toUpperCase(),
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 15.0,
                                                      letterSpacing: 1.2,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                              ),
                                              Align(
                                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                child: FloatingActionButton(
                                                  child: Icon(Icons.image),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        )).toList(),
                                      ),
                                    );

//                                  Row(
//                                  children: <Widget>[
//                                    Container(
//                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 256.0,
//                                      child: ListView.builder(
//                                        shrinkWrap: true,
//                                        itemCount: systemsSnap.data.length,
//                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
//                                          Map<String, dynamic> system = systemsSnap.data[index];
//                                          String systemName = system["system"];
//                                          return Row(
//                                            children: <Widget>[
//
//                                            ],
//                                          );
//                                        },
//                                      ),
//                                    ),
//                                  ],
//                                );
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO action
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.library_books),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO action
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.list),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO action
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.history),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO action
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Basically I changed the `ListView` of the second element of the `Row` for a `Column`, since it already was inside a `ListView` and that was making it have double scroll and the heights weren't expanding the height of the row properly, and also I wrapped the `Row` inside an `IntrinsicHeight` and put `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to the `Row` so the content will fit the height of the `Row`.

The use of `IntrinsicHeight` is expensive, but I don't see another solution for the way you structured the widgets. I recommend you to try to optimize all the structure so you could find a better and optimal solution.

Comment: I'll give this a try and update you with my results. I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work as expected. Thanks anyways, greatly appreciate it. I have updated the source code in the question in case you want to reproduce it.

Comment: I could reproduce it and it worked, let me verify your new code

Comment: ¡Pablo, te saludo con el mayor respeto! This solution works great and it helped me to understand how to better work layouts in flutter. BIG THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stretch the Container to match its parent, use double.infinity for the height and width properties

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Container as a layout')),
    body: Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.yellowAccent,
      child: Text("Hi"),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it doesn't work. I have updated the question to reflect the result after applying your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use `constraints: BoxConstraints.expand()` in some of your containers that you want to expand to fill the row height.

Try something like this:

[image: screenshot of layout]

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Title"),
      ),
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: Text("box 1")),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Container(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                            color: Colors.red,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 2,
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                    color: Colors.yellow,
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 1,
                                          child: Container(
                                              constraints:
                                                  BoxConstraints.expand(),
                                              color: Colors.lightGreen,
                                              child: Text("box 2")),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 2,
                                          child: Container(
                                              constraints:
                                                  BoxConstraints.expand(),
                                              color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                              child: Text("box 3")),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                    color: Colors.yellow,
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 1,
                                          child: Container(
                                              constraints:
                                                  BoxConstraints.expand(),
                                              color: Colors.purple,
                                              child: Text("box 4")),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 2,
                                          child: Container(
                                              constraints:
                                                  BoxConstraints.expand(),
                                              color: Colors.orange,
                                              child: Text("")),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                            child: Text("box 5")),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Container(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child: Text("box 6")),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
```

Comment: This solution works without using `ListView`. The issue with my approach is that I'm using a row that contains a ListView, that contain rows with more list views. Try and test the whole code that I left and you'll see by yourself. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: I tried adding ListView to one of those containers and it seems to works fine.Try putting your ListView code in this structure. Can you also post code with dummy data and without builders so we I can duplicate it on my end.

Comment: If you are nesting hydraulics listview and front tab listview, I suggest keeping their heights fixed, so that hydraulics height is 1/2 of Front tab height and so on.

Comment: I will, please allow me sometime to work on that and I will then update my code with test data and without the builders so you can duplicate on your end. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have edited the question and included the complete source code. Is ready to be copied/pasted for reproduction. Any advice I will greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to use some fixed heights since you are using ListView and FutureBuiulders. If you can get rid of FutureBuilders, you can probably achieve dynamic heights. Notice the hright of 320 on the parent row and height of 160 on child rows.

But have a look at this:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Assemblers Tasks',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Assembly Tasks'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String dropdownValue;

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> buildItems = [];
  getBuilds() {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [];
    items.add({"id": 10, "vehicleModel": "A10", "vehicleNumber": "TEST-00010"});
    setState(() {
      buildItems = items;
    });
  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> buildSections = [];
  getSections() {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [];
    items.add({
      "id": 5,
      "section": "Front",
    });
    items.add({
      "id": 15,
      "section": "Rear",
    });
    setState(() {
      buildSections = items;
    });
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getSystems(String buildSectionId) async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [];
    if (int.parse(buildSectionId) == 5) {
      items.add({
        "id": 4,
        "system": "Hydraulics",
      });
      items.add({
        "id": 20,
        "system": "High Voltage",
      });
    }
    return items;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getBuilds();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 275.0,
                  child: DropdownButton(
                      value: dropdownValue,
                      hint: Text("Choose Build"),
                      isExpanded: true,
                      items: buildItems
                          .map<Map<String, String>>(
                              (Map<String, dynamic> item) {
                            String id = item["id"].toString();
                            String name = item["vehicleModel"] +
                                " " +
                                item["vehicleNumber"];
                            return {"id": id, "name": name};
                          })
                          .toList()
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                              (Map<String, String> item) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: item["id"],
                              child: Text(item["name"]),
                            );
                          })
                          .toList(),
                      onChanged: (String newValue) {
                        getSections();
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownValue = newValue;
                        });
                      }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 150.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "SECTION",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 17.3,
                        letterSpacing: 1.35,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 150.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                  color: Color(0xff444444),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "SYSTEM",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 17.3,
                        letterSpacing: 1.35,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60.0,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 36.0),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 72.0),
                    color: Color(0xff666666),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        "TASK",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 17.3,
                          letterSpacing: 1.35,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(

                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.black12,
                            width: 1.0,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 225,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: buildSections.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        String section = buildSections[index]["section"] != null
                            ? buildSections[index]["section"]
                            : "";
                        String buildSectionId =
                            buildSections[index]["id"].toString();
                        return Container(
                          height: 320,
                          child: Row(

                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(                                
                                width: 120.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border(
                                    right: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.yellow,
                                      width: 1.0,
                                    ),
                                    bottom: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.black12,
                                      width: 1.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                padding:
                                    EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 16.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: RotatedBox(
                                          quarterTurns: -1,
                                          child: Text(
                                            section.toUpperCase(),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 15.0,
                                              letterSpacing: 1.2,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                    ),
                                    Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: FloatingActionButton(
                                        child: Icon(Icons.image),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(

                                child: Container(

                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                  child: false ? Text(" ") : FutureBuilder(
                                    future: getSystems(buildSectionId),
                                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                                        AsyncSnapshot systemsSnap) {
                                      if (systemsSnap.connectionState ==
                                          ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                        return Container(
                                          height: 100.0,
                                          width: 200.0,
                                          child: Text("Please wait..."),
                                        );
                                      } else if (systemsSnap.hasError) {
                                        return Container(
                                          height: 100.0,
                                          width: 200.0,
                                          child: Text("Oops! There was an error!"),
                                        );
                                      }
                                      return Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Container(
                                             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -
                                                 256.0,

                                            child: ListView.builder(
                                              shrinkWrap: true,
                                              itemCount: systemsSnap.data.length,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                Map<String, dynamic> system =
                                                    systemsSnap.data[index];
                                                String systemName = system["system"];
                                                return Row(
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Container(
                                                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                          0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 16.0),
                                                      width: 50.0, 
                                                      height: 160,
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        color: Colors.yellow,
                                                        border: Border(
                                                          right: BorderSide(
                                                            color: Colors.red,
                                                            width: 1.0,
                                                          ),
                                                          bottom: BorderSide(
                                                            color: Colors.black12,
                                                            width: 1.0,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      child: Column(
                                                        children: <Widget>[
                                                          Align(
                                                            alignment:
                                                                Alignment.center,
                                                            child: RotatedBox(
                                                              quarterTurns: -1,
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                systemName
                                                                    .toUpperCase(),
                                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                                                  letterSpacing: 1.2,
                                                                ),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),

                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                );
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      );

                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO action
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.library_books),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO action
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.list),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO action
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.history),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //TODO action
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I appreciate your time and effort. I really need to use the future builder so this suggestion don't fit my needs; Nevertheless, I greatly appreciate your kindness in trying to help.